# Finding a dynamically added ScatterViewItem

Tags: c#, wpf, pixelsense

I have the following:

```
Window window = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive);
ScatterView main = UIHelper.FindChild<ScatterView>(window, "MainScatterView");
        main.Items.Add(type);

//Neither of these work
ScatterViewItem parent = (ScatterViewItem)main.ContainerFromElement(type);

ScatterViewItem parent = UIHelper.FindVisualParent<ScatterViewItem>(type);
```

The documentation says: *When you add an object that is not of type ScatterViewItem, the ScatterView control first wraps the object in a ScatterViewItem control before adding it to the collection* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.controls.scatterviewitem.aspx

How does one get the scatterviewitem that it has been wrapped in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As every other [ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms611045.aspx), ScatterView creates and manages its item containers by an [ItemContainerGenerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainergenerator.aspx), which provides methods to get the container for a certain item or to get the item for a certain container:

```
ScatterView scatterView = ...
object item = ...
ScatterViewItem scatterViewItem =
    scatterView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ScatterViewItem;
```

or

```
ScatterViewItem scatterViewItem = ...
object item = scatterView.ItemContainerGenerator.ItemFromContainer(scatterViewItem);
```